# Where to create Desktop entry for Eclipse?

Tags: unity, launcher, eclipse, .desktop

I recently installed eclipse and also created desktop entry file in

`/usr/share/applications` location as shown in this video 
 [Install Eclipse Luna for Java EE in Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neINFNekWeI) but it didn't work.

And also tried creating in `~/.local/share/applications/` and did what was mentioned there, but still was not able to get the eclipse launcher on the unity laucher.

My Desktop entry for eclipse is

```
Name=EclipseLuna
Name[en]=EclipseLuna
Comment=Integrated Developement Environment
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add

```
 [Desktop Entry]
```

as the first line to your file.

And just in case: Make sure that the file name ends with `.desktop`

And also make sure you have made it executable.

Comment: adding it it did work..i saved it in `/usr/share/application`. but which one should i give more preference to `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/application`

Comment: @ravin Use `/usr/share/application` if this is a multi-user system, you have root access, and all users need to have the Eclipse application shortcut. I personally prefer using my home directory, `~/`, since it's easier to keep track of customization.

Answer (score 0):

You will see eclipse only when browsing all applications, after creating .desktop file as mentioned above
To pin it in unity launcher - run it and right click on it in launcher, then choose needed menu item(don`t remember how it in English ubuntu, something "favourites" may be)

my desktop file(executable) for current(one) user:

```
lenya@JabbaDesktop:~$ cat ./.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse 
Type=Application
Exec=/home/lenya/Eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/lenya/Eclipse/icon.xpm
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=Eclipse
```